# select data from database order by descending in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I selected all data from a MySQL table, I want to fetch records in descending in PHP. How can I do it? please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_name DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select data from the database ORDER ID descending. follow this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC
```

**For Example:**

```
<?php 
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
print_r($row);
}
?>
```